# How to make time series every value as a columns with unique ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a unique ID and time-series data. Time-series data contains 3 macro variables.
I want to construct the data frame, where columns are date , and they are the same. Here are example of initial and expected outputs

---

[image]

---

[image]

Length of ID is not important here

Comment: Please post your data as text (printed dataframe) rather than images.

Comment: Where does the ID come from?

Comment: I think it's just repeated data as the OP says "Length of ID is not important here" @ALollz

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

Recreate OP's dataframe

```
dat = [[3, 4, 1], [4, 5, 3]]
idx = [2017, 2018]
col = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, idx, col).rename_axis('time')
```

#### `pd.concat`

I rap `enumerate` in `dict` where `enumerate` starts from `1` to match OP's `ID` that starts from `1`

```
new = pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df] * 3, 1)), names=['ID']).unstack()

new.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in new.columns]

new

    A2017  A2018  B2017  B2018  C2017  C2018
ID                                          
1       3      4      4      5      1      3
2       3      4      4      5      1      3
3       3      4      4      5      1      3
```

---

#### Details

To see what the concatenated dataframe looks like

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df] * 3, 1)), names=['ID'])

         A  B  C
ID time         
1  2017  3  4  1
   2018  4  5  3
2  2017  3  4  1
   2018  4  5  3
3  2017  3  4  1
   2018  4  5  3
```

If we unstack it

```
        A         B         C     
time 2017 2018 2017 2018 2017 2018
ID                                
1       3    4    4    5    1    3
2       3    4    4    5    1    3
3       3    4    4    5    1    3
```

Only thing left to do is to smash the column levels together, which you can see how I did it above.